# How to redirect a file using function

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to access my file where it contains a home page using a function from another file `(redirect.php)`. `MyWebsite/main/main.html` this is the location of my file that I want to access. I stuck in here `redirect::toMain('main.html');` don't have a idea how to link the full path so I will be directing to the home page. I tried to pass `('main.html')` value to the function `toMain()` but it didn't work. Location of folder below.

[image: Screenshot]

So MyWebsite is the main folder and it contains sub-folder listed below.

- function (folder) contains a redirect function
- main (folder) contains a html. `main.html` where it set as my home page. This is where the user will redirect.

**Class: *redirect.php*** Location: MyWebsite/function/redirect.php

```
<?php

class redirect
{
public static function toMain($location = null)
{
    if($location)
    {
        header('Location: ' . $location);
        exit();
    }
}
}
$a = new redirect();
?>
```

**loginProcess.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('../connection/connection.php');
require_once('../connection/loginCRUD.php');
require_once('../function/redirect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$dbusername = $_POST['loginUsername']; //Store value of textfield in array
$dbpassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];

if(!empty($dbusername) && !empty($dbpassword))
{
    if((new loginCRUD)->readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword)) //If true
    {
       // echo "You are logged in!";
        $_SESSION['loginUsername'] = $dbusername;//Session are stored in array.

        // redirect the user to the home page
        redirect::toMain('main.html');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Incorrect username and/or password";
    }
}

}//end of isset
?>
```

Comment: Will all redirects go to MyWebsite/main/xxxxx?

Comment: @Andrew yes it will redirect to `main.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way that I would do this:

```
class redirect
{
    private static $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/MyWebsite/main/';
    public static function toMain($location = null)
    {
        if($location)
        {
            header('Location: ' . self::$baseUrl . $location);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

The $baseUrl can also be this:

```
private static $baseUrl = '/MyWebsite/main/';
```

Make sure that MyWebsite starts with `http://` or it will redirect to a relative URL. You don't need `$a = new redirect();` since you are accessing the methods statically.

Now you can do this:

```
redirect::toMain('main.html');
```

Comment: Is there a way redirecting to html?

Comment: @Francisunoxx Yes you can after you make the change in my answer.

Comment: @Francisunoxx If it is not absolute (doesn't have http), then you could change the `$baseUrl` part to be `private static $baseUrl = '/main/';`

Comment: I tried your second option but it didn't work. Please see my update post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111665/discussion-between-andrew-and-francisunoxx).